# How to align the lines in a multiline equation while using the space optimally?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, multline

I have a long equation with multiple equalities where I even have to split off the first equation.

- Using 'multline' breaks the alignment of the equations
- With 'align' or 'split' I have to pick an arbitrary point in the first line to align the others to. I also cannot align within `\left(...\right)`.

Is there a way to do it automatically? I'm looking for something that looks like this picture in the end:

[image: example equation]

This is my code right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\pot}{\ensuremath{^{p/2}}}

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
    (t+\tau)\pot-C&\left(m\lor\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s+b|\right)^p\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s+b|^p\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s^p+b^p|\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}\big||B_s|^p-|b|^p\big|\\
    &\leq t\pot+Cm^p+\tau\pot-CM_\tau^p\\
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can align within `left …\right` with the `\MTkillspecial` command defined in § 3.6 (Paired Delimiters) of the `mathtools` documentation.

Comment: i assume you want just one equation number.  you can use `multined` (requires `mathtools`) and use `aligned` for the lines after the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this, with `multline` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nicefrac}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\pot}{\ensuremath{^{p/2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
    (t+\tau)\pot-C\Bigl(m\lor\sup_{s\leq\tau}\abs{B_s+b}\Bigr)^p\\
\begin{aligned}
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}\abs{B_s+b}^p \leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}\abs{B_s^p+b^p}\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}\abs[\big]{\abs{B_s}^p-\abs{b}^p}\leq t\pot+Cm^p+\tau\pot-CM_\tau^p
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools` is for:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pot}{\ensuremath{^{p/2}}}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
    (t+\tau)\pot-C\left(m\lor\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s+b|\right)^p\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s+b|^p\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}|B_s^p+b^p|\\
    &\leq t\pot+\tau\pot-C\sup_{s\leq\tau}\big||B_s|^p-|b|^p\big|\\
    &\leq t\po
t+Cm^p+\tau\pot-CM_\tau^p\\
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

By default `\MoveEqLeft` starts the first line `2em` to the left of the alignment point of the other lines.  If you write `\MoveEqLeft[5]` this will be changed to `5em`, and so on.

Comment: Though, I would not scale those () in the first line that much, big or Big is enough (I'm mostly allergic to left/right constructions)

Comment: @daleif Agreed - but this was to illustrate the OPs wish to be able to use `\left...\right` on such a line.